# Find actual plot limits when specifying partially automatic limits

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How do I find the actual y-range here:

This is just the example from the docs http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html

```
 x = linspace(-10,10,200);
 y = sin(4*x)./exp(.1*x);
 plot(x,y)
 axis([-10 10 0 inf])
```

the ymin value is specified as zero and the max left automatic. If I now query the range with

```
  get(gca,'YLim')
```

I just get `[ 0 inf ]`. How do i determine the actual plot y range used ( it is about `[0 2.5]` for this example..)

edit - *aside*

In case anyone else encounters this - it may be preferable to avoid the issue: make the plot with fully automatic ranging then fix the range as you like so you know exactly what it is, eg.

```
  plot(x,y)
  origYrange=ylim
  origXrange=xlim
  axis([origXrange 0 origYrange(2)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the documentation doesn't tell, it appears that when the first (second) value of `ylim` is set to `-inf` (`inf`) Matlab sets the lower (upper) *y*-axis limit as the minimum (maximum) of all *y* values in the plot. The latter can be known by reading the `'YData'` property of all `'children'` of the axis.

```
yd = get(get(gca,'children'),'YData'); %// get y data of all plots
if iscell(yd) %// if there's more than one plot yd is a cell array of numeric vectors;
              %// otherwise it's a numeric vector
    yd = [yd{:}]; %// combine all values into a single numeric vector
end
ydminmax = [min(yd) max(yd)]; %// computed limits
result = ylim;
ind = isinf(result);
result(ind) = ydminmax(ind); %// replace infinite values by computed values
```

In your example, the result is

```
result =
         0    2.4313
```

Comment: Thanks -- I actually didn't realize the range is set "exactly" to the data range.   For a fully automatic mode it adds space to make a nicer plot.